Create Access Key Pair using Minio Java
Hi there i want to create access key pair in MinIO using MinIO Java Client. Following is the process.

I will login to MinIO via admin user/password and create an access key pair with following IAM Policy.

{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": [
    "s3:DeleteObject",
    "s3:GetBucketLocation",
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket",
    "s3:PutObject"
   ],
   "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket",
    "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
   ]
  }
 ]
}

Can anyone share the Java snippet?
Thanks
